# How to move an image in Android by swiping?

Tags: android

I'm making an Android game, and I'm trying to make an image move up and down when the player swipes up and down. I can't seem to find a way to do this, though. Does anyone here know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to handle touchlistener of the view and move the image accordingly based upon the change in the x and y directions of the touch event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may generally be able to use a `GestureListener` upon which you can move the image up and down as you want.

See this link for more details:
http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html